# Covariance of the product of log normal process and normal procces

Tags: itos-lemma, covariance, lognormal

I tried to compute the following covariance :
$$Cov(e^{\int_{t}^{T}W^1_sds},\int_{t}^{t+1}W^2_sds)$$

where $W^1_t$ and $W^2_t$ are Brownian motions such that  $dW_t^1dW_t^2=\rho dt $

My idea was to use Ito‘s lemma on the process $(e^{\int_{u}^{T}W^1_sds}\int_{u}^{t+1}W^2_sds)_u$ with $u<t$, and then try to find the expectation from the resulting EDP when we take the expectation on both sides of the Ito equation.

But I am not sure if this is working, since the resulting EDP does not have a solution.

Can anyone help me in this regards ?
Do you have other ideas on how to compute this covariance ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'll give it a try, but am not yet 100% sure that it's the way to go.*

### Ansatz:

Let's find the distribution of [the integral of a Brownian motion with respect to time](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-brownian-motion-w-r-t-time) (call it $x$) and find the expectation of the product of two such integrals $x$ and $y$. Then, calculate the covariance as $Cov(x,y)=E(xy)-E(x)E(y)$.

### 1. Distribution of $I(t,T)\equiv\int\limits_{s=t}^{T}W_s\mathrm{d}s$

From [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-rownian-motion-w-r-t-time), we know that
$$
I(t,T)\equiv \int\limits_{s=t}^{T}W_s\mathrm{d}s=\int\limits_{s=t}^{T}(T-s)dW_s
$$

and that $I(t,T)$ is normally distributed with
$$I(t,T)\sim \mathrm{N}\left(0,\frac{1}{3}(T-t)^3\right)$$

### 2. Expectation of $I(t,T)I(t,U)$

By the same way of reasoning (and some weak recollection of [Iso isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry), I'd argue:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(I(t,T)I(t,U)\right)&=\mathrm{E}\left(\int\limits_{s=t}^{T}(T-s)\mathrm{d}W_s\int\limits_{x=t}^{U}(U-x)\mathrm{d}W_x\right)\\
&=\mathrm{E}\left(\int\limits_{s=t}^{T}\int\limits_{x=t}^{U}(T-s)(U-x)\mathrm{d}W_s\mathrm{d}W_x\right)\\
&=\int\limits_{s=t}^{T}\int\limits_{x=t}^{U}(T-s)(U-x)\mathrm{E}\left(\mathrm{d}W_s\mathrm{d}W_x\right)\\
&=\int\limits_{s=t}^{U}(U-s)^2\rho\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(U-t)^3
\end{align}
$$
**N.B.: we assume $U\leq T$.**

### 3. $I(t,T)$ and $I(t,U)$ are bivariate normally distributed

Let's simplify and let $x_1\equiv I(t,T)$, $x_2\equiv I(t,U)$ and $\mathbf{x}=\left(x_1,x_2\right)^T$, also let $\sigma_1^2=\frac{1}{3}(T-t)^3$, $\sigma_2^2=\frac{1}{3}(U-t)^3$ and $\sigma_{1,2}=\frac{1}{3}\rho (U-t)^3$. Then $\mathbf{x}$ is bivariate normally distributed as

$$
\mathbf{x}\equiv\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}\sim \mathrm{N}\left(\mathbf{0},\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1^2 & \sigma_{1,2}\\ \sigma_{1,2} & \sigma_2^2\end{pmatrix}\right)
$$

### 4. Apply the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) (MGF) trick:

Now let's use a little trick I [learned just recently](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/66432/31263). Given a real vector $\mathbf{t}$, the MGF of the multivariate normal distribution is defined as  $\varphi_X(t)\equiv\mathrm{E}\left(e^{\mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{x}}\right)=e^{\mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{t}}$ and, in our case, this is

$$
\varphi(t_1,t_2)=\mathrm{E}\left(e^{t_1x_1+t_2x_2}\right)=e^{\frac{1}{2}t_1^2\sigma_1^2+\frac{1}{2}t_2^2\sigma_2^2+t_1t_2\sigma_{1,2}}
$$

Note that

$$
\left.\frac{\partial \left(e^{x+ty}\right)}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0}=ye^x
$$

thus,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left(e^{I(t,T)}I(t,U)\right)&=\mathrm{E}\left(e^{x_1}x_2\right)\\
&=\left.\frac{\partial \varphi(t_1=1,t_2)}{\partial t_2}\right|_{t_2=0}\\
&=e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma_1^2}\sigma_{1,2}\\
&=\frac{1}{3}\rho(U-t)^3e^{\frac{1}{6}(T-t)^3}
\end{align}$$

### 5. Putting all together

Thus, for Brownian motions $W^1_t, W_2^t$ with $dW_1dW_2=\rho dt$

$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Cov}\left(e^{\int\limits_{s=t}^TW^1_s\mathrm{d}s}\int\limits_{x=t}^UW^2_x\mathrm{d}x\right)&=\mathrm{E}\left(e^{x_1}x_2\right)-\mathrm{E}\left(e^{x_1}\right)\mathrm{E}(x_2)\\
&=\mathrm{E}\left(e^{x_1}x_2\right)\\
&=1/3\rho(U-t)^3e^{\frac{1}{6}(T-t)^3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I believe there is a slight inaccuracy in the computation of Expectation of I(t,T)I(t,U), but thanks for the detailed answer and the ideas that you have explained. Thumbs up from me.

Comment: Hi, you are welcome to point that one out! My Ito calculus is a bit *rusty*

Answer (score 0):

Hint (too long for a comment). The integrals
$$
X_1:=\int_t^{T_1}W^1_s\,ds\,,\quad\quad X_2:=\int_t^{T_2}W^2_s\,ds
$$
are two normals with expectation zero, variances
$$
\sigma_i^2=\int_t^{T_i}\int_t^{T_i}\min(u,s)\,du\,ds\quad\quad\text{(can be solved) }\,,\quad\quad i=1,2
$$
and covariance
$$
\gamma=\rho\int_t^{T_1}\int_t^{T_2}\min(u,s)\,du\,ds\quad\quad\text{(can be solved). }
$$
It should be straightforward to calculate
$$
{\rm Cov}(e^{X_1},X_2)\,.
$$

Comment: Hi, I think you beat me to a comment yesterday (the exp expansion9, and you beat me to an answer today. :-D.

Comment: @Kermittfrog : what comment was that ?

Comment: Maybe I mistook you for somebody else- sorry, then.